# How can I parse internal transactions with light node?

Tags: cpp-ethereum, light-clients, internal-transactions, parser

is that possible to receive all transactions from new block with light node and parse all and even internal transactions with the help of its api?

Comment: What data are you hoping to glean by parsing the internal transactions?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with Web3 API and what could you do here is first use:

*web3.eth.getBlock('latest')*

This will return all the latest block data including transactions array with all the transaction hashes inside this block. Then you can loop the transaction hashes array and use:

*web3.eth.getTransaction(transactionHash)*

This will return the transaction data including from, to, value and more.

Comment: Doesn't explain how to parse internal transactions (i.e. message calls).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot. Some full node clients have functionality ([i.e. the Parity Trace module](https://wiki.parity.io/JSONRPC-trace-module.html)) for parsing transaction message calls, though these are not even standardized in the [ETH JSON-RPC protocol](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC). Even with these modules, it is not simple to parse all internal transactions (assuming you mean ETH transfers) from a block.

Parsing internal transactions requires a live EVM to capture all message calls that occur as a result of a transaction. Light clients (in general, as I do not know which one you are using) are not actually processing transactions, but just receiving the required data and verifying that it exists in the blockchain.